# How to print a variable that has the same name as an inputted string?

Tags: python, string, variables, printing, global-variables

[Python] I have a function that's supposed to print the values of global variables. It takes in 1 argument (the global variable name), but as a string. How do I print out the global variable value that has the variable name of the string?

```py
dogs = 3
cats = 4
def get_value(variable_name: str):
    print(variable_name)
```

I expect the output of `get_value(dogs)` to be `3`, but the actual output is `dogs`.

I can't change the type value of the parameters. It has to be str.

Comment: Do you mean `get_value('dogs')`? Because from what you've posted, `get_value(dogs)` would actually print `3`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's built-in [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function:

```
dogs = 3
cats = 4

def get_value(variable_name: str):
    print(globals()[variable_name])

get_value('dogs')
get_value('cats')
```

Output:

```
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
z = 20

def change(variable) :
    variable = str(variable)
    print(variable , type(variable))

change()
```

Output:

```
20 <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Please try to explain what the code is doing instead of posting the answer (which may be incorrect though)